# error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier mType when passing a map by function

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors, maps, std

When I declare the below function:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
void setTypeByBanknote(tsBanknotes &tsBanknotes, std::map<char, std::vector<byte>> &mType);
```

My compiler shows the following error:

> error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier mType

But if I do the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
typedef std::vector<byte> tvByteVector;
void setTypeByBanknote(tsBanknotes &tsBanknotes, std::map<char, tvByteVector &mType);
```

My compiler does not show any error and compiles correctly

Is there any way to pass this map as an argument without using typedef ?

I'm using `visual 6.0 as IDE`, I know it is very old. Is the problem because of the old IDE ? I do include vector and map libraries.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::map<char, std::vector<byte> >
                               ^^^^
```

You need a space between two `>`s like `> >`. Otherwise VS 6.0, which is very old, gets confused with operator `>>`. It's better to update the compiler.